# How to use sql query in sql functions

Tags: mysql, sql

There is table like below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
title(varchar)  |  date(datetime)       |  id(int, primary key)
---------------------------------------------------------------
title1          |  2015-07-24 01:19:48  |  1
title2          |  2015-07-25 07:19:23  |  2
title3          |  2015-07-26 23:19:18  |  3
title4          |  2015-07-27 11:19:45  |  4
title5          |  2015-07-30 02:19:40  |  5
```

Since the date value is saved as [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time),  I have to convert it to local time zone.(In my case it's GMT+9)

I tried

```
SELECT convert_tz(date, '+00:00', '+09:00') 
FROM 
my_table
```

but doesn't work.

How can I select rows with converted time values? Is it proper to use sub query in my case?

What I want to get is like below...

```
2015-07-24 10:19:48
2015-07-25 16:19:23
2015-07-27 08:19:18
2015-07-27 20:19:45
2015-07-30 10:19:40
```

Comment: `MYSQL` <> `SQL SERVER` you got to keep that in mind so choose one

Comment: You got to explain "doesn't work" . What is the result when you run the query

Comment: @Fireblade It says that I should check the manual

Comment: Is `date` your original column name

Comment: @Fireblade yes its original name is "date"

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00cf3/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`date`,INTERVAL 9 HOUR)
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Oh woops yes, I was SQL Server. Will edit query, thanks @jpw

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following you will get your expected result

select *,DATEADD(hour,9,date) as NewDate from my_table;

Thanks.